# Pandas sum values in rows of different sizes

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with multiple values for many different "product numbers". I am trying to sum these values and write the result to a new column directly next to the first instance of the "product number". See below for dataframe. FYI this dataframe represents a snippet of a much larger dataframe I have already created in python.

```html
╔═════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ product number     value         NEW COLUMN ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ 1                  3             9          ║
║ 1                  2                        ║
║ 1                  4                        ║
║ 2                  1             7          ║
║ 2                  6                        ║
║ 4                  2             9          ║
║ 4                  1                        ║
║ 4                  2                        ║
║ 4                  4                        ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby().transform('sum')` to create the new column on all position. Then use `duplicated` to remove duplicate:

```
df['NEW COLUMN'] = (df.groupby('product number')
                      ['value'].transform('sum')
                     .mask(df['product number'].duplicated())
                   )
```

Output:

```
   product number  value  NEW COLUMN
0               1      3         9.0
1               1      2         NaN
2               1      4         NaN
3               2      1         7.0
4               2      6         NaN
5               4      2         9.0
6               4      1         NaN
7               4      2         NaN
8               4      4         NaN
```